# Problems using rxjs inside Angular2 CLI project

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I created a new Angular2 project using Angular CLI `v1.1.3` and Node `v6.11.0`. I wanted to create a simple rxjs example using rxjs `v5.4.2` (automatically installed by angular CLI).

Here is my `App.component.ts` file with my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/observable'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private obs: Observable) {
    obs.fromEvent(document, 'click')
      .filter(function(c) {return c.clientX > window.innerWidth / 2 })
      .take(10)
      .suscribe(function(c) {console.log(c.clientX, c.clientY) })
  }
}
```

This is the Error message I receive:

```
ERROR in .../src/app/app.component.ts (11,28): Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

**Q: How to get this example running properly using rxjs?**

---

The example suggests using

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
          .filter(function(c) {return c.clientX > window.innerWidth / 2 })
          .take(10)
          .suscribe(function(c) {console.log(c.clientX, c.clientY) })
```

**How do I achieve to get the example running using `Rx.`?**

---

**Edit 2:**
fixed the rxjs issues but now c.clientX and c.clientY isn´t working anymore. When I hover over clientX in the IDE it tells me `Property clientX does not on type {}`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
import { Operator } from 'rxjs/operator';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/suscribe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
      .filter(function(c) {return c.clientX > window.innerWidth / 2 })
      .take(10)
      .subscribe(function(c) {console.log(c.clientX, c.clientY) })
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:

See the working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTHZ6ie5IEtjJ2jkVHOP?p=preview) here. If you click on the right half of the preview, the cords are printed in the console. It works online but not on my local machine with the same code...

Comment: I think you can just remove `Rx` and it would be a valid call for Observable in Angular and Rxjs. because you import only Observable from RxJs, not the whole RxJs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fromEvent()` method is a static method that needs to be called on `Observable` class not on an instance:

```
Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
```

See for more info: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent

So the problem is actually not in the parameter because you shouldn't be using it anyway :).

Comment: If I change my constructor to `constructor() {
    Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
      .filter(function(c) {return c.clientX > window.innerWidth / 2 })
      .take(10)
      .suscribe(function(c) {console.log(c.clientX, c.clientY) })
  }` it still doesnt´t work. The error says, that `fromEvent` does not exist on type Observable

Comment: you need to import fromEvent and other operators i think

Comment: So what's the problem? You're already importing `Observable` from `rxjs/Observable` so you can use just `Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')` or I don't know what doesn't work for you

Comment: I added all operators manually, but now my c.clientX and c.clientY isn´t working anymore...see the edited code above.

Comment: When I hover over clientX in the IDE it tells me `Property clientX does not on type {}`

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: @martin Here is the working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTHZ6ie5IEtjJ2jkVHOP?p=preview) . If you click on the right side of the preview, the coords are shown in the console. It works on Plunkr, but not on my local machine

Comment: @JohnDizzle I'm not using your machine so I can tell you why it doesn't work there :)

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor declares an argument `obs` to be of type `Observable`. `Observable` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), meaning that it requires a type parameter.

Think about it this way: you want `obs` to be an `Observable` "of something", i.e. containing items of type something.

You need to write `constructor(private obs: Observable<Something>)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because this Observable need an argument. If it is array, you need Observable< Array< any>> or try Observable< Response>